# json find parent node of node where key named "id" equal to "value"

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, asp.net-web-api

I have JSON similar to this with
many id and ref keys:

```
jSon = {
        "id":"node1",
        "name":"Languages",
        "rel":"",
        "children":1,
        "step":1,
        "path":1,
        "nodes":[
            {
                "id":"node2",
                "name":"Java",
                "rel":"Pure Object Oriented Prog",
                "children":1,
                "step":2,
                "path":2,
                "nodes":[
                    {
                        "id":"node3",
                        "name":"C#",
                        "rel":"Framework",
                        "children":0,
                        "step":3,
                        "path":3,
                        "nodes":[]
                    },{
                        "id":"node4",
                        "name":"C++",
                        "rel":"OOPS",
                        "children":0,
                        "step":3,
                        "path":4,
                        "nodes":[]
                    }]
            }]
    };
```

In Objective-C how can I reach to parent node of element where key is `id` and value is let's say `node4` or something else.

In xcode, I am trying to parse a JSON data from `MVC` web `API`.

My `web.api` JSON is [this](http://www.katalogaplikasyonu.com/api/companies/?companypinnumber=111234567)

When I comment out `Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects`, JSON becomes very big, usually like 35MB.

When I use `PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects` , .net puts `id` and `ref` keys for repating objects.

When traveling through JSON, if a reach a `ref` key with value `asdfg`, I  have to search back node with key `id` and with value `asdf.

Is this possible in `Xcode` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to either do a depth-first or breadth-first search, depending on which you think will find the node fastest. Here's a very un-tested attempt at the code you'd need:

**Depth-first**

```
- (id)nodeWithID:(NSString *)identifier inDict:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
    id node = nil;
    if ([dict[@"id"] isEqualToString:identifier])
    {
        node = dict;
    }
    else
    {
        // Traverse the inner nodes to perform a depth-first search
        for (NSDictionary *innerNode in dict[@"nodes"])
        {
            node = [self nodeWithID:identifier inDict:innerNode];
            // Break once a node is found
            if (node != nil)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return node;
}
```

**Breadth-first**

```
- (id)nodeWithID:(NSString *)identifier inDict:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
    id node = nil;

    if ([dict[@"id"] isEqualToString:identifier])
    {
        node = dict;
    }
    else
    {
        // Perform a breadth-first search
        NSMutableArray *nextDictionaries = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:dict[@"nodes"]];
        while (node == nil && [nextDictionaries count] > 0)
        {
            dict = nextDictionaries[0];
            if ([dict[@"id"] isEqualToString:identifier])
            {
                node = dict;
            }
            else
            {
                [nextDictionaries addObjectsFromArray:dict[@"nodes"]];
                [nextDictionaries removeObjectAtIndex:0];
            }
        }
    }

    return node;
}
```

* EDIT ***
Or if you want to be fancy and make a category on `NSDictionary`:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, NSIdentifierSearchOptions) {
    NSIdentifierSearchOptionBreadthFirst = 0,
    NSIdentifierSearchOptionDepthFirst = 1
};

@interface NSDictionary (IdentifierSearch)

- (id)objectForKeyIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier options:(NSIdentifierSearchOptions)options;

@end

@implementation NSDictionary (IdentifierSearch)

- (id)objectForKeyIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier options:(NSIdentifierSearchOptions)options
{
    id object = nil;
    switch (options)
    {
        case NSIdentifierSearchOptionBreadthFirst:
        {
            object = [[self class] breadthFirstNodeWithID:identifier inDict:self];
            break;
        }
        case NSIdentifierSearchOptionDepthFirst:
        {
            object = [[self class] depthFirstNodeWithID:identifier inDict:self];
            break;
        }
    }
    return object;
}

+ (id)breadthFirstNodeWithID:(NSString *)identifier inDict:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
    id node = nil;

    if ([dict[@"id"] isEqualToString:identifier])
    {
        node = dict;
    }
    else
    {
        // Perform a breadth-first search
        NSMutableArray *nextDictionaries = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:dict[@"nodes"]];
        while (node == nil && [nextDictionaries count] > 0)
        {
            dict = nextDictionaries[0];
            if ([dict[@"id"] isEqualToString:identifier])
            {
                node = dict;
            }
            else
            {
                [nextDictionaries addObjectsFromArray:dict[@"nodes"]];
                [nextDictionaries removeObjectAtIndex:0];
            }
        }
    }

    return node;
}

+ (id)depthFirstNodeWithID:(NSString *)identifier inDict:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
    id node = nil;
    if ([dict[@"id"] isEqualToString:identifier])
    {
        node = dict;
    }
    else
    {
        // Traverse the inner nodes to perform a depth-first search
        for (NSDictionary *innerNode in dict[@"nodes"])
        {
            node = [self depthFirstNodeWithID:identifier inDict:innerNode];
            // Break once a node is found
            if (node != nil)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return node;
}

@end
```

Comment: Nice recursive algorithm solution but not exactly. Aren't there any preBuilt search functionality which i could get all nodes with @"id" key. And how will i reach the parent of found node ? I am looking for something like a dom search !

Comment: No, there's no built-in way. I updated the code to be even fancier for you.